# Connectionreseterror: (errno 104) connection reset by peer: Python script deployed in AKS

Tags: python, azure, rest, kubernetes, azure-aks

I recently deployed a python script using a docker image within a AKS pod.
The python code to do the request:

```
response = requests.get("https://google.com")
```

The Pod deployment file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test1
spec:
  containers:
 - name: test1
    image: <linktodockerfile>
  imagePullSecrets:
 - name: test1
```

However I seem to get a 'Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) no matter what I try to make a request towards.

Does anyone have any idea. I am new to AKS and trying to make the simplest possible test

Thanks,

Comment: can you share your dockerfile? Also, did you try with a simple program which logs hello world in the console

Comment: Do you have any specific configuration that may block this traffic ?
Can you provide entire python code and Dockerfile ?